# Implied do statement in a read statement written in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am working on some old code. More precisely what that code does. It is written in fortran95.

The bit I am interested in is this:

```
1 read(09,'(52x,i6,i4,12i2)',end=2)hj,fix(1),(fix(k),k=4,15)
some data wrangling
goto 1
2 continue
```

What I think this does is that 1 line of the input is read and assigns these values to these temporary objects, the scalar hj, and the array fix(1) and fix(4:15). It then does some data wrangling which are not important and then goes back via this goto statement, reads the next line, until it hits end of file (EOF), where it is pointed towards segment 2.

My question is twofold:

1. Is this understanding correct?
2. Is there any utility in this from a performance standpoint?

Comment: In short, yes and no, although `hj` and fix` are not containers.  `hj` is a scalar variable and `fix` is an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer steve. I'll clarify the post, it was not very specific to talk about container's instead of scalars and arrays. So there is basically no point in doing it this way (performance?) instead of a more legible way?

Comment: Reading from a file isn't where I worry about performance.  I would as a matter of style use a do-loop instead of the labeled `goto` with an appropriate level of indentation to make the code more readable.

Comment: For formatted I/O, the performance of the implied DO loop is the least of your concerns. For unformatted I/O, compilers I have worked on would convert that to an array section and copy the data in one piece; that isn't an option for formatted I/O.